# Linking a CSS file to a .ASPX file

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Its my first introduction into using aspx pages from originally creating html pages.

I am trying to link an external CSS page to the index.aspx page and it is not pulling through anything. 
Maybe im not referencing it correctly or it needs to be in a specific directory, Im not too sure.

See below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestTitle</title>
     <link href="Styles/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <p class="testp">HI MY NAME IS HARRY</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS code

```
body {
    font-size: 36px;
}

.testp {
    font-family:'Bradley Hand ITC';
}
```

Nothing hectic, im just testing the waters.

See directory below

[image: IMAGE HERE]

If i could please get som help , or maybe a better way of doing it correctly.
Thanks

Comment: Usually it has virtual path like this: `<link href="~/Styles/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

Comment: Or `<link href="/Views/Home/Styles/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`. But it looks like you are mixing plain html and MCV....

Comment: @VDWWD Sorry, im still trying to learn techniques and best practices. Is there a reason i wouldn't be able to mix html and MVC? Maybe there is another way i can implement it through using asp.net instead of plain html?

Comment: You can mix it. But usually you use one or the other. MVC is a framework that with the help of programming languages creates a html page for the browser to see. But if you want to use plain html (which is fine) you don't need the overhead of a framework.